# Total up how many men and how many women in a column. Possibly in order to repopulate the planet

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Trying to search through a column in a db, and pull out the total number of males, and total number of females.

This data is stored in the db as f and m in the whatsex column.

```
    $query = "SELECT whatsex, COUNT(*) FROM soberdata GROUP BY whatsex";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $sexdb = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $totalmale = $sexdb['m'];
    $totalfemale = $sexdb['f'];
    echo $totalfemale." & ".$totalmale;
```

This code outputs nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sexdb have only "whatsex" and "COUNT(*)" columns. You should use one of them

try

```
print_r($sexdb);
```

and look if some of results meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

Your query is going to return a `whatsex` value, and a `COUNT(*)` value, not `m` or `f`. Doing a `var_dump($sexdb)` would show you what's in the array.

Comment: Damn, one second before me :/ GL!

Comment: Thanks for the help - when I run the SQL through phpmyadmin, it gives me a table with 
12    f
2     m
How do I route that into php variables using var_dump?

Comment: the mysql_fetch_array function returns an array keyed with the column names you've queried. like I said, do `var_dump($sexdb)` AFTER you run the query and you'll see what the array keys are to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating a multi-dimensional array as flat.  You could do this to flatten it

```
$query = "SELECT whatsex, COUNT(*) as total FROM soberdata GROUP BY whatsex";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $$row['whatsex'] = $row['total'];  // this makes a variable ($m or $f) using the value of the row
}

$totalmale = !empty($m) ? $m : 0;
$totalfemale = !empty($f) ? $f : 0;
```

You should empty check the results of the db in case there is no male or female entries to avoid errors.

Comment: Is there a way to do the query that will give me a flat array?

Comment: An opensource function in moodle can be found here https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/MOODLE_19_STABLE/lib/dmllib.php just search for the function recordset_to_menu

Comment: This wouldn't work either... `$sexdb['m']` is invalid, as 'm' is the value not the index.

Comment: oops, you are correct, oversite on my behalf. I've updated my post to not mislead